# How about a “Filter bounty” option in featured questions?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

How about adding an option to filter featured questions by the value of their bounty? I.e. I want to challenge questions with bounty above +250 and would like to find them easily.

Comment: Interesting idea! (I would've seen this sooner, but I filter all bounties under 600 points)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree this would be a nice feature:

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&**filter=bountypoints**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&filter=bountypoints)

But realistically it is quite a big task.

In the mean time, I whipped up this query that will list questions with bounties from the start of the month: ([direct link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/255568/see-questions-that-has-or-had-bounties-this-month))

```sql
SELECT P.id As [Post Link], V.BountyAmount, V.CreationDate As [Bounty Start], P.Score, 
  P.ViewCount, P.Title, P.Tags, P.Body, P.AnswerCount 
FROM Posts P INNER JOIN Votes V ON P.Id = V.PostId
WHERE DATEPART(m, V.CreationDate) = DATEPART(m, getdate())
  AND DATEPART(yyyy, V.CreationDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, getdate())
  AND V.BountyAmount > 0
  AND P.ParentId IS NULL
ORDER BY V.BountyAmount DESC, V.CreationDate DESC
```